# How to do custom model binding in Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have POST action in controller like below

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn([ModelBinder(typeof(SignInRequestModelBinder))] SignInRequestModel request, string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }

    var result = await _accountService.SignInAsync(request);

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }

    return Json(result);
}
```

I have a request model like this

```
public class SignInRequestModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember Me")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

I post data to Model binder via jQuery AJAX
But I can do that like this

```
var request = bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request;
var model = new SignInRequestModel()
{
    Email = request.Form["Email"],
    Password = request.Form["Password"],
}
```

This is hardcoded but how can I do that another way. When post data custom model binder do that instead of writing request.Form[]...

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In this scenario, you don't need to create your own binder. The **built-in** model binder has already done it for you. So the easiest way is to let the ASP.NET Core bind the model **automatically**:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   public async Task SignIn(
       [ModelBinder(typeof(SignInRequestModelBinder))] 
       [FromForm]SignInRequestModel request,  // the [FromForm] is required when you're using an ApiController
       string returnUrl = null
   )
   {
       ... 
   }
   ```

   (Or if you're using a plain Controller (instead of `ApiController`), you don't even have to use the `[FormForm]` attribute)

---

2. In case you want to bind the form data by yourself, you can use `Reflection` to inspect all the properties dynamically:

   ```cs
   public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   {
       if (bindingContext == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext)); }
       var request = bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request;

       var model = new SignInRequestModel();
       var pis = typeof(SignInRequestModel).GetProperties();
       foreach(var pi in pis){
           var pv = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(pi.Name); // prop value
           pi.SetValue(model,pv.FirstValue);                  
       }
       bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
       return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
   ```

   This also works. But the first way is preferred because that's a robust way.